# how to prevent floating div from not extending the siblings

Tags: html, css

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/ur2w4p86/

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b">
        asdfsdf
    </div>
</div>
```

If i add left padding to .b, its content don't get affected until padding is more than the width of .a, which is being floated. So basically floating element extends the div underneath it like sibling b.

I dont want that. I want 2nd div to be adjacent to a and take rest of the space. I can't use inline block because then i've to define the exact width for 2nd div which is not what i want either and there is no css only way to tell 2nd div to fill in available space to right.

Comment: Dint understand your exact requirement, so what do you want your outcome to look like ?

Comment: when i apply padding to .b it can't be seen being applied on left side as left side has been extended  and is too far away to have an effect on content.

Comment: It's happening because you have .a floated left and a 100% width on .b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occurring because you have .b floated left (which takes it out of the flow) and .a width at 100%. If you want to keep your layout this way, you'll need to use a `margin-right` on .a instead of `padding-left` on .b

```
.a {
    background-color: green;
    width: 26%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: isn't this like a hack

Comment: It's not really a hack, it's the only way to solve it with your current layout.

Comment: i added overflow auto on nonfloating element and it did the same thing

Comment: `overflow: auto` will clear the left float and more than likely cause .b to move under .a